# Create task-salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, tasks

Guys i hope i would get some help here.

I am trying to automatically create tasks. Creating task is very simple as I know.
But the scenario is different here.

I have an account where I'm doing some financial planning and I am capturing the financial planning done date in a date field.

I want to create a task in every quarter after 3 months of the financial planning done date. There is no limitation, task creation should go on until the account is deleted.

This is not possible with Time Based Workflow because there is no limitation in task creation as how long it will continue.

I am not able to do this with a  trigger either. Because Trigger will fire only when a record is created or edited, and wouldn't make sense to generate an unlimited amount of tasks from a trigger.

Are there other ways in the force.com platform in which I can built this type of functionality ?

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange silent_killer,  seeing someone gave you a negative vote (but didn't leave a comment) I've taken the liberty to modify your question slightly, bringing out what you've already considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an apex [batch process](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) and [schedule](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) it to run every 3 months. So that it will create tasks. The logic would check if,

1. the account is active or not and select all the account which is active in the start method of your batch
2. Create the task for the accounts in the scope of the execute method